Create a button in two custom objects
this is my first Apex Class and Visualforce.
EDIT DESCRIPTION_18.11.2024:
I want to generate PDF from TWO custom objects - Faktura__c and Przychody_nowe__c.
I added a button to generate PDF via Visualforce Page on the Faktura__c module after Andrii Muzychuk's comment.
But now you can't see data from two modules: Faktura__c and Przychody_nowe__c.
We are returning in SandBox environment because we don't have Code Coverage - 0% (0/11) for Apex Class.
FakturaTriggerHandler is Code Coverage  100% (10/10).
Apex Class:
    public class FakturaPDF {

    public FakturaPDF(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public Faktura__c faktura {get {
                                     if (faktura == null)
                                     faktura = new Faktura__c();
                                     return faktura;
                                    }
                               set;}
    
    public List<Przychody_nowe__c> przychody {get; set;}
    
    public FakturaPDF(){
        this.faktura = [SELECT Name, Nadawca__c, Odbiorca__c, Adres__c, NIP__c, Numer_Projektu__c, Okazja_biznesowa__c, 
                               Data_sprzeda_y__c, Termin_p_atno_ci__c, Rodzaj_faktury__c
                        FROM Faktura__c
                        WHERE Id = :this.faktura.Id
                        ];
                        

        
        this.przychody = [SELECT Name, Nazwa_Przychodu_tre_na_fakturze_cd__c, Przych_d_jednostkowy_netto__c, Ilo__c, Przych_d_ca_kowity_netto__c, Przych_d_ca_kowity_brutto__c
                              FROM Przychody_nowe__c
                              WHERE Faktura__c = :this.faktura.Id
                             ];
    }
}

Visual Page:
        <apex:page standardController="Faktura__c" extensions="FakturaPDF" renderAs="PDF">
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
          <title>Dane do faktury z Salesforce MaxtoITS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
  

            <center>
                <h1 class="heading heading--main">Dane do wystawienia faktury:</h1>
            </center>
            
            
            
            <div class="box--half">
           
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Nadawca:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Nadawca__c}</span>
            
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Odbiorca:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Odbiorca__c}</span> <br></br>
                <span>Adres: {!faktura.Adres__c}</span> <br></br>
                <span>NIP: {!faktura.NIP__c}</span>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Numer projektu:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Numer_Projektu__c}</span>
            </div>
            
          
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Okazja biznesowa:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Okazja_biznesowa__c}</span>
            </div>
            
           
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Data sprzedaży:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Data_sprzeda_y__c}</span>
            </div>
   
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Termin płatności:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Termin_p_atno_ci__c}</span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="box-half">
                <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Rodzaj faktury:</h2>
                <span>{!faktura.Rodzaj_faktury__c}</span>
            </div>
   
            
            <div class="box--half">
            <h2 class="heading heading--sub">Lista pozycji na fakturze:</h2>
            
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nazwa</th>
                        <th>Kwota jednostkowa [zl netto]</th>
                        <th>Ilość</th>
                        <th>Wartosc netto [zl]</th>
                        <th>Wartosc brutto [zl]</th>
                        
                    </tr>
            
            <apex:repeat value="{!przychody}" var="przy">
            
             <tr>
                            <td>{!przy.Name}</td>
                            <td>{!przy.Przych_d_jednostkowy_netto__c}</td>
                            <td>{!przy.Ilo__c}</td>
                            <td>{!przy.Przych_d_ca_kowity_netto__c}</td>
                            <td>{!przy.Przych_d_ca_kowity_brutto__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
            </table>
           </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>

Trigger:
public with sharing class FakturaTriggerHandler 
{
    private boolean m_isExecuting = false;
    private integer BatchSize = 0;
    public static boolean IsFromBachJob ;
    public static boolean isFromUploadAPI=false;
    
    public FakturaTriggerHandler(boolean isExecuting, integer size)
    {
        m_isExecuting = isExecuting;
        BatchSize = size;
    }
            

    public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Faktura__c> newFaktura)
    {
        system.debug('Faktura Trigger On Before Insert');
    }
    public void OnAfterInsert(List<Faktura__c> newFaktura)
    {
        system.debug('Faktura Trigger On After Insert');
    }
    public void OnAfterUpdate( List<Faktura__c> newFaktura, List<Faktura__c> oldFaktura, Map<ID, Faktura__c> newFakturaMap , Map<ID, Faktura__c> oldFakturaMap )
    {
        system.debug('Faktura Trigger On After Update ');
  
    }
    public void OnBeforeUpdate( List<Faktura__c> newFaktura, List<Faktura__c> oldFaktura, Map<ID, Faktura__c> newFakturaMap , Map<ID, Faktura__c> oldFakturaMap )
    {
        system.debug('Faktura Trigger On Before Update ');
    }
   }

Test FakturaPDFtest:
@isTest
public class FakturaPDFtest{

@isTest static void FakturaPDFTest() {


        Przychody_nowe__c przy = new Przychody_nowe__c();
        przy.Typ_przychodu__c = 'Sprzęt';   
        przy.Status__c = 'Roboczy';
        przy.Nazwa_Przychodu_tre_na_fakturze_cd__c = 'Test';
        przy.Stawka_VAT__c = 23;
        przy.Przych_d_jednostkowy_netto__c = 100;
        przy.Ilo__c = 1;
        przy.Okazja_biznesowa__c = '006Sb00000CLeEtIAL';
        przy.Data_sprzeda_y__c = System.today().addMonths(6);
        przy.Termin_platnosci__c = 1;
    
        insert przy;
    
    Test.startTest();
    
    przy.Status__c = 'Do sprawdzenia przez Dział Logistyki';
    update przy;
    
 
    
    
        Faktura__c fak = new Faktura__c();
        fak.Termin_p_atno_ci__c = 1;   
        fak.Status__c = 'Roboczy';
        fak.Rodzaj_faktury__c = 'Elektroniczna';
        fak.Data_sprzeda_y__c = System.today().addMonths(6);
        fak.Okazja_biznesowa__c = '006Sb00000CLeEtIAL';
    
        insert fak;
     
        List<Przychody_nowe__c> przychody = [SELECT Id, Name 
                                             FROM Przychody_nowe__c 
                                             WHERE Name = :przy.Nazwa_Przychodu_tre_na_fakturze_cd__c AND Faktura__c = :fak.Id];
        System.assertEquals(0, przychody.size());
    
       Test.stopTest();

  }
}


Hi and welcome to SFSE. Have you managed to create a VF-based action successfully in your sandbox? Have you included the page layout with that action in your change set when deploying to production? Please add these details via an [edit] of your question, rather than as answering comments. Thanks. (BTW, always "Salesforce", never "SalesForce".)

I think we might need a little bit more information on what you are trying to achieve on the page itself, let alone a deployment error (I would focus on that later.) Is the page working as intended when you pass in the id to the vf page? /apex/yourPageName?id=yourIdHere

Thank you for interest in my case. I added more information to description.

You lack specifying standardController attribute on apex:page tag. Your Visualforce should start with
<apex:page standardController="Faktura__c" extensions="FakturaPDF" renderAs="PDF">

The documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_associate.htm

not only that, but the controller constructor signature has to change from custom controller to standard controller.

The constructor of the extension class has nothing to do with having a Visualforce page being available for a button for an object. Yes, it will get you a context like a record on which it was clicked (or records). But it is not mandatory.

good point but kind of a best practice

Agree. I just checked a few of my implementations - there is no class without ApexPages.StandardController standardController attribute of the constructor.

Thank you for interest in my case. I added your code and I have an error:  Error: Unknown constructor 'FakturaPDF.FakturaPDF(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'

Update: The buttom on SandBox environment is works but we don't have a data form Faktura__c and Przychody_nowe__c. I'm looking for where it's wrong...


My guess is that you use word "module" instead of the correct word "object". Please use the right terms if you want a correct answer on your question. 2. My second guess is that you created a Change Set and tried to deploy the code but run into a problem. Now that is completely different problem from what you initially stated in the question. But still, I would guess you just haven't added all the objects and fields in your Change Set.

